Order error using ls command
UBUNTU 22.04.1.LTS
I have a strange error. using the command ls:
$ ls I*
IVÌ_VAL
IVÌ_SIL
IVÌ_VAL

As you can see, there are two errors:
The first is that there are two identical entries  IVÌ_VAL
The second is that IVÌ_SIL is after and before the two instances of IVÌ_VAL: and the alphabetical order is not retained.
This is the hex code of the results: it doesn't explain both the errors.
4956c38c 5f 56414C 0A
4956c38c 5f 53494C 0A
4956c38c 5f 56414C 0A


Edit your text and include the actual commands, i.e. copy (and paste here) from the terminal. Piping text into ... | od -t x1z will also display bytes (in hex) together with the actual text.
